# Unable to integrate ICICI payment gateway in Android

Tags: java, android, payment-gateway

I have to integrate ICICI payseal payement gateway in Android application.But I have no idea how to use it.?Can anyone suggest way to integrate it in the same.

Regards,
Surjit Kumar

Comment: what you have searched yet?

Answer (score 1):

ICICI do not provide any Android supportive platform or code, you will have to get it done using phone Gap, Send Request to web page from app and capture request from webpage and process based on gateway response. Please let us know id you have any more doubts about in web flow.